# how to implement dynamic slide creation-javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am doing a project in Phone Gap-android.I am implementing functions in java script.I have implemented SWIPE VIEW using [this](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/).

Now,I will share the coding i used to implement this so,that it can be helpful to you in finding out my mistake.

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
//Your options here:
mode:'horizontal',loop: true, speed : 500, freeMode : true, freeModeFluid : true,
});
```

---

```
value= VALUE_FROM_DB.split("||");
 for (k=0;k<value.length;k++)
 {
    if (value[0] == paramName1)
   {
      return unescape(value[k]);
      console.log("no of swipe views ");
   }
    var val = k+1;
    var superdiv = document.getElementById('swiper-wrapper');
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var divIdName = 'swiper-slide'+val;
    console.log("div name: "+divIdName);
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    newdiv.setAttribute('class','swiper-slide');
    newdiv.style.width = "25%";
newdiv.style.height = "30%";
    superdiv.appendChild(newdiv);
    var cnt1 = '<div id="container" class="container"><span><img src="img/cause_'+val+'.png" style="float:left;"></span><div id="clinicals'+val+'" class="clinical"><span ><h5>'+value[k]+'</h5></span></div></div>';
    console.log("check value"+cnt1);
    document.getElementById(divIdName).innerHTML=cnt1;
    console.log("clinical values: "+value[k]);
console.log("processsing parameter loop ");
var searchString = window.location.search.substring(1),i,val,params = searchString.split("&");
}
```

**html code**

```
<div id="swipe_body">
    <div class="swiper-container swiper-threshold">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper" id="swiper-wrapper">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css code:**

```
.clinical       
{
    font-size:15px;text-justify:inter-word;margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px; margin-right:10px; margin-bottom:10px;
}
.container
{
 background:url(img/value_bg.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; background-size:100% 100%; display:block; width:304px; height:250px;text-align:justify;
}
.container span
{
 width:auto; height:30%; display:block; overflow:hidden;float:left; 
}
```

now, my output is not the desired one.

Only 1 slide is being displayed.Swipe functionality is not being implemented and the rest other values are no to be seen.

WHAT SHOULD I DO?
please guide me!!.

**SECOND ALTERNATIVE,I IMPLEMENTED IS AS FOLLOWS(after the no of swipe views):**

```
var val = k+1;
            var superdiv = document.getElementById('swiper-wrapper');
            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            var divIdName = 'swiper-slide'+val;
            console.log("div name: "+divIdName);
            newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
            newdiv.setAttribute('class','swiper-slide');
            superdiv.appendChild(newdiv);
     --->       var cnt1 ="var newSlide = mySwiper.createSlide('<div id="container" class="container"><span><img src="img/cause_'+val+'.png" style="float:left/>;"></span><div id="clinicals'+val+'" class="clinical"><span ><h5>'+value[k]+'</h5></span></div></div>', 'swiper-slide', 'span');
            document.getElementById(divIdName).innerHTML=cnt1;
            document.querySelector('.swiper-slide');
            console.log("split value: "+value[k]);
```

the output error I get is

```
05-20 12:11:20.214: E/Web Console(6855): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at file:///android_asset/www/clinical.html?var%20id=0:171 (the line differentiated with an arrow)
```

**THE MOST IMPORTANT FACT IS THAT,ALL 5 VALUES ARE BEING DISPLAYED IN THE LOG.BUT,1 slide is being SEEN.**

**in simple words swipe functionality is not working.**

Comment: **ANY SOLUTIONS PLEASE**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call mySwiper.reInit(), right after your slides creation. Also take a look at the Slides API http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php#slidesapi

Comment: thank you,for the answer..yeah i had fixed it.i just initiated the swiper and used it.

Answer (score 0):

Call Your Swiper again with `reInit`, at the time of dynamic creation.
In my case, the product had various color instances,the first load was working properly,on dynamically loading new content by click on color,The swiper plugin fails to detect the newly added dom.

The solution is to call `reInit();`

**use case**

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {});

function dynamic_content(){mySwiper.reInit();}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it's too late, but it seems the other answer is outdated because of update. For me the following line worked

```
mySwiper.appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide">My Slides"</div>')
```